# How to create a GUI in the bottom right corner of the screen?

Tags: user-interface, screen, autohotkey

I want to create a transparent timer in the bottom right corner of the screen. The [Gui - Syntax & Usage](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#PosSize) documents only show commands for the leftmost and topmost margin (`xm`, `ym`; `x0`, `y0`), so I don't know how to set it up properly.

Here is my code:

```
#Singleinstance, Force
Gui, Color, white
Gui, Font, S9, Tahoma
Gui, Add, Text, BackgroundTrans vT, 00:00:00
Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption
WinSet, TransColor, white
Gui, Show
SetTimer, Update, 1000
Update:
 GuiControl,, T, % A_Hour ":" A_Min
Return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
; 50 is number of pixels from the right of the screen
xval:=A_ScreenWidth-50 
; 25 is number of pixels from bottom of the screen
yval:=A_ScreenHeight-25 
Gui, Show, x%xval% y%yval%
```

Comment: does this too depend on the screen size? Is there a way to locate it right above the taskbar clock?

Comment: Yes. You can experiment by trying offsets other than the 50 and 25 that I chose. Alternatively you can use the Window Spy program that comes with AHK to determine the exact screen coordinates where you want to place your GUI.